# Why do I get the wrong solution? Difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can you help me solve this?
$a_{n} + 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} = 0$ where $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 4$

I tried the following:
$$\lambda^{2} + 2\lambda + 1 = 0 \iff (\lambda + 1)^2$$
Double root: $\lambda = -1$
$$a_n = (A + Bn)(-1)^n$$
Inserting initial values:
$$0 = (A + B(0))(-1)^0 \iff A = 0$$
$$4 = A + 4B \iff B = 1$$

Result:
$$a_n = (-1)^n\cdot n$$

But the correct answer is:
$$(-1)^n \cdot -4n$$

Comment: Where do you get $A+4B$ from?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $4 = (A+B(4))(-1)^4$

Comment: But $n=1$, not $n=4$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh well... I see it.

Comment: Yes, sorry about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging $n=1$ should give you $-B = 4$ so that $B=-4$ and the correct result follows.